# Java Swing: how to make scrollable view of items that may have buttons inside of them?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I'm trying to do scrollable list of items that may have buttons inside of them. It's contained within JTabbedPane, and after thorough Googling I'm still not sure how to proceed.

A picture of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: quick sketch]
Best thing that comes to mind is JScrollPane with items as JPanels with BoxLayout and they have "name of item | button | button", although I might be plain wrong and JScrollPane is unable to accept multiple Components.

What I need help with is adding these JPanels to a JScrollPane. How to do that? I tried simple "this.add(name of panel)" and it doesn't work.

```
    // MainWindow:
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Overview", new OverviewTab());
    tabbedPane.addTab("Warehouse", new WarehouseTab());
    tabbedPane.addTab("History", new HistoryTab());

    public class WarehouseTab extends JScrollPane {
    WarehouseTab(){
        this.setBorder(null);
        this.add(new WarehouseItem());
        this.add(new WarehouseItem());
        this.add(new WarehouseItem());
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class WarehouseItem extends JPanel {
    WarehouseItem(){
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        JButton sell = new JButton("Sell");
        JButton tax = new JButton("Return tax");
        JLabel name = new JLabel("Item name");
        this.add(name);
        this.add(tax); 
        this.add(sell);
    }
```

I also tried packing my JPanels into Container and then pointing JScrollPane's viewport to it, as suggested on some other forums, but it didn't work either. What else should it try?

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It is not clear if you want the `JTabbedPane`  in a  `JScrollPane` , or  each `WarehouseItem` warped by  a  `JScrollPane`. If the later use `add(new JScrollPane(new WarehouseItem());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> although I might be plain wrong and JScrollPane is unable to accept multiple Components.

Yes, you're right, `JScrollPane` manages a single "view".  What you should so is start with a separate `JPanel` which acts as the "primary" container for your other elements and then wrap that in a `JScrollPane`

```
public class WarehouseTab extends JPanel {
    public WarehouseTab() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(new WarehousePane());
    }
}

public class WarehousePane extends JPanel {
    WarehousePane(){
        setLayout(...); // Set an appropriate layout for overall needs
        this.add(new WarehouseItem());
        this.add(new WarehouseItem());
        this.add(new WarehouseItem());
    }
```

Also, have a look at [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) which provide more information about how `JScrollPane` works